# Java - Split by delimiters

Tags: java, regex, split

Given `_<A_>_<B_>_<Z_>`, I want to extract `A, B, C` in an array.

Basically `_<` is the starting delimiter and `_>` is the ending delimiter.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please attempt to implement yourself and then ask questions specific to issues you're having with implementation.

Comment: `.replaceFirst("(?s)^_<(.*)_>$", "$1").split("_>_<")`

Comment: @Deco, You are right.. I should have put it up.. But what I tried was very basic i.e., Sequentially look for a delimiter and populate an array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple - cut out first opening and last closing , and then split it by close-open

```
string.replaceFirst( "^_<(.*)_>$", "$1" ).split( "_>_<" );
```

Comment: No, don't split at all. That's what capture groups are for.

Comment: +1 This is a perfectly valid, working solution. (And it does return directly the resulting array. Not like my solution, where the array has to be created.)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match only the content of the tags.

```
String text = "_<A_>_<B_>_<Z_>";

List<String> Result = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern p = Pattern
    .compile("(?<=_<)" + // Lookbehind assertion to ensure the opening tag before
        ".*?" +          // Match a less as possible till the lookahead is true 
        "(?=_>)"         // Lookahead assertion to ensure the closing tag ahead
        );
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){
    Result.add(m.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You extract them using [capture groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).

Comment: an how you get array from groups :) ? from _<A_>_<B_>_<Z_>_<X_>_<N_>

Comment: @SergeS Is that a trick question? You just make one.
List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=1; i <= match.groupCount(); i++) {
  ret.add(match.group(i));
}
return ret;

Comment: ok, so show an working example code, because i cannot get it work via groups

Comment: See stema's post. His solution is the proper one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10136780/52573

Comment: @SergeS solution is also a very nice one, I don't think mine is better than his (his is shorter). Its a matter of taste.

Comment: ok, i agree i missed groups, but next time it is better to put example, because without example someone (as me) can miss point

Answer (score -2):

split by `_<` to get 2 elements, take the 2nd and split it by `_>` to get 2 elements, take the 1st and split it by `_>_<` to get A, B, C

Comment: No, don't split at all. That's what capture groups are for.